# Botpress can't connect to messenger

Tags: chatbot, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am making my first bot on botpress. On trying to connect botpress with messenger by inputing app id, app secret and access token through UI, I am getting forllowing errors : 
`An error has been returned by Facebook API. Status: 400 (Bad Request) (#100) callback_url should represent a valid URL`.

[image: botpress-connector error]

Even when manually input these values in `botpress-messenger.config.yml` same error is shown.

but the fallback url gets validated on messenger developer console.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if your domain is existing. Also, remove https  [image]